# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe') Angular12

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs6

I am getting below error while sending ajax request,

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
```

ajax-loader.interceptor.ts class

```js
 export class AjaxLoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 private loaderProp = 'ajax_loader';
 constructor(private activeAjaxLoadersService: ActiveAjaxLoadersService) {}

 intercept(
   request: HttpRequest<any>,
   httpHandler: HttpHandler
 ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   console.log('ajax loader', request);
   const loaderName = request.headers.has(this.loaderProp)
     ? request.headers.get(this.loaderProp)
     : null;
   console.log('loaderName', loaderName);
   const updatedHeaders = request.headers.has(this.loaderProp)
     ? request.headers.delete(this.loaderProp)
     : request.headers;
   const updatedRequest = request.clone({ headers: updatedHeaders });
   console.log('updatedHeaders', updatedHeaders, updatedRequest);
   this.updateLoaderState(loaderName, XHR_REQUEST_STATES.PROGRESS);

   return httpHandler.handle(updatedRequest).pipe(
     tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
       console.log('httpHandler', event);
       if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
         this.updateLoaderState(loaderName, 'success', event);
       }
     }),
     (responseError: any): any => {
       if (responseError instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
       }
     }
   );
 }
```

`Providers code:`

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AjaxLoaderInterceptor ,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

Same code was working in angular 8 but after upgrade to v12 it broke.

I have created reproducible code example in stackblitz , Please find it here [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-facebook-login-example-uqrreb?file=src%2Fapp%2F_helpers%2Fajax-loader.interceptor.ts)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [next.handle(request) in multiple HTTP interceptors fails: undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635885/next-handlerequest-in-multiple-http-interceptors-fails-undefined)

Comment: Actually same code was working in angular version 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax-loader.interceptor.ts file add return statement after  if condition like this below

```
   if (responseError instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
       }

    return responseError;
```